# how to call javascript function from another domain?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

working with a asp.net 3.5 solution with various projects. I have a javascript file called MyScript which sits in WebprojectA. What I would like to do is refer to this scriptfile in my WebProjectB? example some code in aspx page in WebProjectB:

```
//this script sits in WebProjectA:
    <script src="../Scripts/Myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: How is this different to [your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7974131/615754) from three hours ago?

Comment: Yeah, looks like a repost of the exact same question to me.  This one should get closed as a dup.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything wrong with doing it like this?

```
//this script sits in WebProjectB:
    <script src="http://www.webprojecta.com/Scripts/Myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your will have to share a common directory structure or reference via a site url.  The best approach is to use a CDN.