# can I call a javascript function in another project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I call javascript function from another project in same solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974131/how-can-i-call-javascript-function-from-another-project-in-same-solution)

I am using an asp.net 3.5 web solution with js which contains 2 projects ProjectA and ProjectB. Is it possible to call a js function which is defined in ProjectA in a scriptfile from somewhere in ProjectB? what would the script reference be?

Comment: Almost the same wording as another user's question last week: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7974131/615754 - is this homework or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first have to load the script from the project A while the Project B loads. You can try the code below

```
// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cscript = Page.ClientScript;

// Register the client resource in the page.
cscript.RegisterClientScriptResource(rstype, 
     "CompanyName.ProjectA.Scripts.YourScript.js");
```

Now if you call the method in the YourScript.js file from the project B , i should work. 
Note: Please make sure that you load the 'YourScript.js' file before you call the method in that file.

Comment: it does not work:( did you try to run the code?